# understanding of Artin's proof of "$A_n$ is generated by $3$-cycles"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A quick proof for "$A_n$ is generated by $3$-cycles ($n\geq 4$)" is calculating the product of possible two $2$-cycles. I read the following different proof from Artin's *Algebra*(2nd):

> This is analogous to the method of row reduction. Say that an even permutation $p$, not the identity, fixes $m$ of the indices. We show that if we multiply $p$ on the left by a suitable $3$-cycle $q$, the product $qp$ will fix at least $m+1$ indices. Induction on $m$ will complete the proof.
>
> If $P$ is not the identity, it will contain either a $k$-cycle with $k\geq3$, or a product of two $2$-cycles. It does not matter how we number the indices, so we may suppose that $p=(123\cdots k)\cdots$ or $p=(12)(34)\cdots$. Let $q=(321)$. The product $qp$ fixes the index $1$ as well as all indices fixed by $p$.

Could anybody explain how the statement is proven in his proof? (I don't quite understand what he is doing in the first paragraph.)

Comment: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ecroot/3cycle.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first paragraph gives an overview of the method used. You start with any $p\in A_n$, written as product of disjoint cycles, then keep multiplying it with $3$-cycles until the product is the identity.